# Nillradical is prime ideal, then the ring is not a product ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, schemes

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $nill（A）$　is not a prime ideal.
This is just a characterization of $SpecA$ to be irreducible.

Then, according to the argument of general topology, irreducible deduces connected.
So,to translate this into ring theory,
We should like to say 'if $nill（A）$　is not a prime ideal, then $A$ cannot be a product of non-zero ring.'

But I cannot show the last proposition with ring theory.
Thank you for your help, my teachers.

Comment: "nill(A) has no prime ideals" You're saying, the nilradical, as a ring, contains no prime ideals?  Anyhow, the title make sense but the body of the question confuses me, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the rings have unit. Suppose that $A=U\times V$. $(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$ implies $(1,0)\in Nil(A)$ or $(0,1)\in Nil(A)$ contradiction since $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are not nilpotent.